# Function call segmentation fault in C before first line of a function

Tags: c, fault

I call the `register_descriptor` function:

```
    fprintf(stderr, "Calling register_descriptor\n");
    register_descriptor(
            &rtptxArgs.chan[rtptxId], 
            rtptxArgs.rtspd_handle, rtptxId, 
            inet_ntoa(sin->sin_addr), 
            ntohs(sin->sin_port), 
            gAudio_ctrl.instance[rtptxId].sc_info[0].rtp_port);
}
fprintf(stderr, "after register_descriptor\n");
```

which looks like this:

```
static void register_descriptor(
    VCAPVENC_RTPTX_CHANNEL *pchan,
    z3_rtspd_handle rtspd_handle,
    int chId, char *ip, unsigned short vport, unsigned short aport)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "first line of register_descriptor\n");
    fflush (stderr);
    fsync (fileno (stderr));
    struct z3_rtspd_media_descriptor desc = {
        .uri = "",
        .id = 0,
```

But the `"first line of register_descriptor\n"` message doesn't get printed out. Instead, the output looks like this:

```
Calling register_descriptor
signal 11 (Segmentation fault) si_code x1, address is 0x4 from 0x44fa8
```

Comment: does your `sin` contain `NULL`? why don't you put a check for NULL before dereferencing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Have you printed the value in `gAudio_ctrl.instance[rtptxId].sc_info[0].rtp_port` in the calling code?  Is one of the two function calls in the argument list giving trouble?  Where does the debugger say the fault is happening?

Comment: Possibilities - `rtptxId` is out of range for either `rtptxArgs.chan[]` or `gAudio_ctrl.instance[]`; or `sin` is not a valid pointer; maybe a couple others. Can't really tell without the additional code. What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that sin was NULL. Should have checked.